# Fetch error when calling response.json()

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

In my API class, I have a code like below,

```
let response;
try {
  response = await fetch(requestUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    timeout: REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      id,
      accNumber: acctId,
      invNumber: invId,
      fromDate,
      toDate
    })
  });
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error(
    'Unexpected error occurred while invoking ATOM Invoice API',
    error
  );
}
foo(cloneDeep(response));
const result = await response.json();
--- some more code ---
```

Then in another class, I have implemented `foo` method,

```
async foo(response){
    let result;
    let errorDescription;
    try {
      result = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    --- some more code ---
}
```

When running the above code I get the following error thrown from `foo` function:

```
{
    "name": "FetchError",
    "message": "response timeout at <my request URL in here> over limit: 10000",
    "type": "body-timeout"
}
```

I would like to know why this happens and what should I do to avoid this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `foo(cloneDeep(response));` why?

Comment: You are asking why I cloned it or why am I calling `foo` method for?

Comment: why are you cloning the response (incorrectly)? you probably want something like `foo(response.clone());` if you want to clone the response

Comment: I used `lodash` library's `cloneDeep` method. What did I do wrong in it? I'm confused.

Comment: if you want to use the body more than once, use the `response.clone()` method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone - but WHY do you want to clone it?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I want to asynchronously validate the response and continue with the normal flow. My validation logic should not slow down the rest of the process

Comment: fair enough - does the code work now?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout?It might  be actual timeout from the API. Why don't you try using a rest client like postman to confirm if the api works without timing out?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. Your fix worked. :-)

Comment: @ShyamBabu No, I did not. The API actually sent the response correctly.

Comment: @JaromandaX Following up the above question, could you clarify why `cloneDeep` does not work but `response.clone()` works?

Comment: Probably some internal stuff isn't exposed to JavaScript so clonedeep doesn't clone it. Not sure. I have no idea about the internals of fetch response object