# 'cloneDeep' of 'lodash' vs 'clone' method of Response in 'Fetch API'

Tags: response, lodash, fetch, clone

I want to know the difference between cloning a response object resolved by Fetch API using `response.clone()` and `cloneDeep(response)` (using `cloneDeep` method of `lodash` library)

The reason I ask this is because of this question raised by me earlier.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460134/fetch-error-when-calling-response-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think lodash supports copying stream objects which `Response` has one for the response body. There also could be hidden properties that lodash can't see that the user agent manages behind the scenes.

Comment: What did you mean by user agent?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan that’s the technical name for a web client such as a browser

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a little more. How copying a stream object like body behaves differently than any other object? And what did you mean by hidden properties? Is it something that response is inherited from?